# BingAds report getting fails even after hours

Tags: php, api, bing-api, bing-ads-api

On php trying to get cost reports by campaignIds. Authentication is ok, submitting the report is ok.
But when retrieving via;

```
$bingAds->getCampaignPerformanceReport($accessToken, $clientAccountID, $customerId, $ReportRequestId);
```

some campaigns get results and others fail. On Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/request-download-report?view=bingads-13), it says;
"*When the status is Success, use the URL that the service provides to download the report*"
I clearly see that I have success in the call but downloadUrl is null.
[Screenshot of Xdebug with null and success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLe9A.png)

Bingads ask to do 2, 15 minute polling, if exceeds an hour wait and try again(not a great direction but it is what it is, bing).

My question is, is there anyway to check why a submitted report could fail(via reportId)
Or some reports just fail with no reason( once request submitted is, you just have to hope to get it, does not seem like a solid design). I even try for one day report, which should have just KBs of data, still no result, just success with no downloadUrl

Comment: Were you able to follow-up with BingAds support on this? 
You might receive a TrackingId after making the call, providing that maybe helpful to support/ provide here. There is not enough information here as to what was your original command to create the Campaign Performance report, etc.

Comment: Another question is on the bing ads forum, no response. Information I have is calling getCampaignPerformanceReport fails, it is not an initial authentication as it is authenticated. First issue is on documentation it says success should provide URL, it does not. Second one is the errors from Bingads have no detail. You can't pinpoint where the problem could be. If success and no URL can be addressed, it could solve the problem

Comment: I understand. 
Would you be able to file a support ticket with Microsoft BingAds at https://about.ads.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-advertising-support ? 
I would recommend you have the microsoft account details (with which you login) ready.